# BasicRecurrentLayer with no bias and linear activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Trying to design a small neural network for modeling a LTI system, I'd like to configure a **BasicRecurrentLayer** with these particular settings:

- *No bias vector should be used* (I've tried the option **"Biases"-> None**, but it does not work for a BasicRecurrentLayer)
- *The output should be directly the weighted sum of its inputs* (I'd like to use **Identity** instead of **Tanh** as activation function, which is the default value for this kind of layer)

I could apply a **ElementwiseLayer[ArcTanh]** at the output of the layer, to somehow undo the effect of **Tanh**, but still the recurrent connection going backwards to the input port would not be the desired one.

As far as I can see, I can't configure BasicRecurrentLayer to my own needs, so must I then create a new user-defined layer, and make the necessary recurrent connections manually into a NetGraph? How could I do it? I'm a newbie in the neural networks field, and any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, kind regards,

Comment: Could you please include the code you have developed so far in your attempts? That would give a valuable starting point for people to play around with and help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0];
batchSize = 16;
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {batchSize, 10, 8}];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {batchSize, 1}];
```

```
net = NetChain[
   {
    BasicRecurrentLayer[4],
    SequenceLastLayer[],
    LinearLayer[1],
    ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]
    },
   "Input" -> {"Varying", 8}
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
NetExtract[net, {1, "Biases"}] // Normal
```

> {0., 0., 0., 0.}

```
netT = NetTrain[net, X -> Y, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10];

NetExtract[netT, {1, "Biases"}] // Normal
```

> {0.00993016, 0.00993503, -0.00995534, -0.00985054}

[`LearningRateMultipliers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LearningRateMultipliers.html) is useful here.

```
netT2 = NetTrain[net, X -> Y, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10, 
   LearningRateMultipliers -> {{1, "Biases"} -> 0}];

NetExtract[netT2, {1, "Biases"}] // Normal
```

> {0., 0., 0., 0.}

You can also look at [`NetFoldOperator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetFoldOperator.html) to create customized RNN.

Comment: OK for the method to get rid of the biases, but why did you add a LogisticSigmoid at the end of the chain? I just need a linear function at the output.

Comment: Hello @Danel. You can delete `LogisticSigmoid`. In this example, `Y` is in the range [0, 1].